# gfortran 7, READ command and libraries

Tags: fortran, runtime-error, homebrew, gfortran

I have recently upgraded to gfortran 7.2 from 6.x using homebrew on OSx. I am now getting errors from the `READ` statement that I was not getting previously. A minimal example that generates the error is:

```
PROGRAM read_test

  IMPLICIT NONE
  CHARACTER :: c
  INTEGER :: i

  c='1'
  READ(c,*) i
  WRITE(*,*) i

END PROGRAM read_test
```

If I compile the code with:

```
gfortran read_test.f90
```

it works fine and simply writes '1' to the screen. However, if I compile with:

```
gfortran -L/usr/local/lib read_test.f90
```

I get a run-time error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input
```

I have no idea why including the library would generate this error, or why it would change the behaviour of how the `READ` statement works. This did not happen with 6.x. Any ideas?

Comment: which library did you load?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Which version is your libgfortran? Gfortran 6 uses libgfortran 3 and gfortran 7 uses libgfortran 4, IIRC. But it should automatically request the correct one. Which libraries are in `/usr/local/lib`? Why do you use it in your compilation command?

Comment: @vladimir-f For this example code I do not need the /usr/local/lib. However, for more complicated codes I include `-L/usr/local/lib` in the compile commands when I need external libraries, such as `FFTW3`. In `/usr/local/lib` I see `libgfortran.3.dylib`, `libgfortran.a`, `libgfortran.dylib`, `libgfortran.la` and `libgfortran.spec`.

Comment: @jmh I do not (as far as I know) load any specific libraries. The behaviour of the code just changes depending on whether or not I have the '-L/usr/local/lib' statement in the compile command. I guess this must be loading some libraries somehow to account for the change...

Comment: If I run `brew doctor` it tells me that `libgfortran.3.dylib`, `libgfortran.a` and `libgfortran.la` were all unbrewed and may therefore be problematic. Could this be the problem? Can these be safely deleted?

Comment: Very likely yes.

Comment: Okay, that seems to have fixed my problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by outdated versions of the libraries `ibgfortran.3.dylib`, `libgfortran.a` and `libgfortran.la` that were left around on my system in `/usr/local/lib`. Once I removed these the code works as it should.